# VBA If loop with external conditions

Tags: vba, if-statement

I'm trying to execute a IF loop in a excel Vba project where the if conditions comes from a string but it doesn't work. I think the error occurs because of the And logic operator problem the program not recognized as logic operator.

Do you have an idea to solve my problem.

```vb
Dim tx As String
tx = "2<1 And 3>0.5"
If tx Then
    exh = 1
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You tx variable is declared as text, and isn't interpreted. You can try to `Evaluate` tx :

```
Dim tx As String
tx = "2<1 & 3>0.5"
If Application.Evaluate(tx) Then
    exh = 1
End If
```

Note : I replaced 'And' by '&'.